# Combining similar methods

Tags: c#, optimization, methods

I currently have two methods:

```
CalculateDaily()
{
     List<string> tempList;

     // Effective query.  not what is really passed
     tempList = "SELECT timestamp FROM table1 WHERE date = today";

     var total = tempList.Sum();
}
```

And:

```
CalculateTotal()
{
     List<string> tempList;

     // Effective query.  not what is really passed
     tempList = "SELECT timestamp FROM table1"

     var total = tempList.Sum();
}
```

My question is should I keep them separate, or would it be feasible to combine them into a single method and run an `if` check? Something like:

```
Calculate(bool daily)
{
     List<string> tempList;

     if(daily)
          tempList = "SELECT timestamp FROM table1 WHERE date = today";
     else
          tempList = "SELECT timestamp FROM table1";

     var total = tempList.Sum();
}
```

Comment: The preferred practice is to decompose and reduce coupling, not increase complexity. One function, one responsibility. But better is the suggestion below to combine what's common and then subclass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a method that provides a start- and an end-date. Then you can use it however you like.

```
public static int Calculate(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate)
{
    string sql = @"SELECT SUM(timestamp) 
                   FROM table1 
                   WHERE date BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate";
    using(var con=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con))
    {
        con.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@startDate", startDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@endDate", endDate);
        int sum = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is going to sound like a very silly question, but is it possible to parameterize a query that is being passed into another method?  For instance, the query I write is passed to a `Query()` that actually does the connection and execution.  I'm still so very new at querying databases, and I'm learning more by the day, but this eludes me.  That, or I haven't had enough coffee today.

Comment: @TyrionLannister: I don't know your `Query` method. Maybe it needs overloads with parameters. In my opinion it's rarely a good idea to encapsulate db functionality in a db-class. On that way it's f.e. difficult to ensure that connections get closed as soon as possible(as with the `using` statement above). It doesn't add much but can hurt.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it this way:

```
Calculate(bool daily)
{
     List<string> tempList;

     tempList = "SELECT timestamp FROM table1"

     if(daily)
          tempList += " WHERE date = today";

     var total = tempList.Sum();
}
```

or a more parameterized version (some pseudo-code):

```
Calculate(bool daily)
{
     List<string> tempList;

     tempList = "SELECT timestamp FROM table1 WHERE (@Date IS NULL OR date = @Date)"

     if(daily)
          @Date = today;
     else
          @Date = null;

     var total = tempList.Sum();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about...

```
Calculate(bool daily)
{
     List<string> tempList;

     tempList = "SELECT timestamp FROM table1";

     if(daily)
         tempList += " WHERE date = today";          

     var total = tempList.Sum();
}
```

Though the "Effective Query" part needs clarification.

Comment: The query is a sample query that get's passed.  It could be `"SELECT names FROM table1"`.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to be sure you were actually using inline SQL as opposed to translating for an ORM or whatever.  In that case, for security reasons be sure to parameterize the params like D Stanley pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a general method for scalar queries

```
// Assumes parameter names @0, @1, @2 ... in the query.
public static T ExecuteScalar<T>(string query, params object[] parameters)
{
    using(var conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)) {
        for (int i = 0; i < parameters.Length; i++) {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@" + i, parameters[i]);
        }
        conn.Open();
        return (T)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
}
```

Then create overloaded methods for your queries

```
public static decimal SumTable1Amount()
{
    return ExecuteScalar<decimal>("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table1");
}

public static decimal SumTable1Amount(DateTime date)
{
    return ExecuteScalar<decimal>(
        "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table1 WHERE date = @0",
        date);
}

public static decimal SumTable1Amount(DateTime fistDate, DateTime lastDate)
{
    return ExecuteScalar<decimal>(
        "SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table1 WHERE date BETWEEN @0 AND @1",
        fistDate, lastDate);
}
```

Calling different queries is very easy now, so there is no point in creating a single parametrized method any more.